# Is this a hawk, or an eagle?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I saw this large bird gliding fairly low over the trees while hiking in the late afternoon in some hills near Taipei recently. It seemed *quite large* compared to what I normally see here. It's quite difficult to gauge, but I'd guess the wing span was one meter or so.

It made that shrill, descending, single "peeeew" sound that I associate with birds of prey (probably mostly from old movies or TV commercials).

Is it at all possible to guess if this is a hawk or an eagle from these cell phone snapshots? These are cropped out of the full resolution originals. A half-size original for scale is also included.

[image]

[image] [image]